# UIAlertController is too slow in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, ios9.3

UIAlertController is too slow when performing any button action in iOS 9.3. Not sure if it's iOS 9.3 problem or missing something to configure it properly.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                               message:@"This is an action sheet."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"one"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          NSLog(@"You pressed button one");
                                                      }];
UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"two"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                           NSLog(@"You pressed button two");
                                                       }];
```

On iPhone Simulator, the action sheet button tap takes more than 10 seconds to print the log in console. Can anyone please let me know how to disable the transitions on iPhone Simulator or increase the speed.

Comment: Can you check if it is presented on main thread?

Comment: @negaipro - thanks for the help. Nothing to do with UI main thread, the issue was iPhone simulator "Slow animations" pointed by BorisVerebsky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Debug/Slow Animations in simulator menu.

[image]

Comment: Right on the spot! Thanks ;-)